# Abort linux polling

Tags: linux, file-descriptor, abort

I am porting an audio mixer from directsound on Windows to alsa on Linux. I am polling on, let's say, 16 file descriptors using the system call "poll". Now i need to be able to abort the polling somehow. On Windows i am using the WaitForMultipleObjects using events and when i need to abort the waiting i just SetEvent on one of the events causing the wait to return. Is there any way to mark a file descriptor in Linux "ready" so that the poll will return?

I have taken a look at ppoll but i am not familiar with signals and i don't want to handle unnecessary race conditions. I mean, if alsa can set the file descriptors to "ready" i should also be able to ;)

Comment: What's wrong with adding a timeout?

Comment: I don't want to poll in user-mode.

Comment: Can you define more precisely what you mean by "user-mode" polling ? Either you are writing kernel code, and then you don't do system call, or you write user code, and I can't see what's wrong with poll ? Perhaps you mean "application code using your library" won't use polling, but must be able to interrupt the call ?

Comment: Call it whatever you like but it is still a very bad idea to poll in "user-mode", "user-land", "not in the kernel", "in the application", "in the client", "bla bla bla" - since you are forcing the scheduler to switch context all the time causing huge overhead and bad performance. Using system calls goes deep into "kernel-mode" making the process truly asleep maximizing the performance and minimizing overhead. Also, with timeout i am specifying an absolute time of latency witch is not a part of my cross-platform API - this should be implementation defined i believe.

Comment: My code uses a separate thread that has the purpose of decoding and streaming audio data to directsound / alsa when an event occurs. When no event is triggered the thread is put to sleep using system calls (WaitForMultipleObjects / poll) minimizing unnecessary context switches. When i want to close the thread or add more descriptors i abort the waiting causing it to wake up and then either close the thread and join or "update" the waiting with the new descriptors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you make a pipe using the `pipe()` function, you can add the output end into your `poll()` list. Then you can write something into the input end of the pipe and your poll will return. Much like your Windows version.

You'd need to be using something asynchronous like threads or signal handlers to make that work.

Another option would be to use `sigaction()` to set a signal handler **without** the `SA_RESTART` flag. You could use an unused signal like `SIGUSR1` or one of the real-time signals. When you want to interrupt the `poll()` then you send that signal and `poll()` will return with -1 and errno set to EINTR.

It would be possible for a different signal to interrupt your `poll()` as well, unless you used `sigmask()` to block unwanted signals.

Comment: I like your solution with the extra descriptor as a way of exiting the poll but what about the system call "ppoll"? Quote "ppoll() allows an application to safely wait until either a file descriptor becomes ready or until a signal is caught." Using ppoll i should be able to send some kind of signal when i want to abort the poll, i just dont know a lot about signals as i really have never used them.

Comment: Hey i think i get that - the ppoll has a mask, blocking signals other than the one i use to abort the poll? If i specify 0 as the mask the poll wont be interrupted by any signals and if i make a mask for just the signal i use it will only abort on my signal? I think i have to look into signals then :)

Comment: I did this to abort the poll:

//Interrupt poll in the streaming thread
signal(SIGUSR1, ignore_handler);
pthread_kill(thread->native_handle(), SIGUSR1);

where ignore_handle is an empty void taking an int.

Comment: @Alex Solution with another descriptor is nice and will work. If you want to handle such number of descriptors you should consider epoll or libevent library to gain better performance.

Comment: @Alex Interrupting poll() with a signal is not a good solution, due to a race condition. There's no way to make sure that poll() has already been called (i.e. has entered the kernel) -- so that it actually will be interrupted by the signal -- or in the signal handler to reliably prevent poll() from being called. The solution with the additional file descriptor (pipe) is really the only one that works. The answer should be amended.

Answer (score -1):

Use the timeout and check the exit condition.

```
while (not exit_condition):
    int poll(struct pollfd *fds, nfds_t nfds, int timeout);
```

Comment: This will be user-mode polling.